# Problema ao subir APK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Estou tentando subir um apk para Google Play e recebi a seguinte mensagem:

> Você fez o upload de um APK que usa a versão 5208000 do Google Play
>   Services. É preciso usar a versão 5100000 ou inferior.

No meu arquivo buil.gradle eu tenho a seguinte dependência da Play

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, qual é o código da versão 5100000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código que esta usando, compila a versão mais recente do Google Play Services, porém a mudança ainda não foi "totalmente implementada".

Tente usar:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

Comment: A ideia é essa mesmo, só complementando... consegui com essa versão `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0+'`